# Cordova App in VS2015 is exiting the app while returning from photolibrary

Tags: file, cordova, rendering, visual-studio-2015, exit

It is working fine during debug in device and failing when disconnected from debug.

my cordova app is as follows.

Index page with Contenthost leads to Home.

Home has a button that navigates to page 1.

Page1 has a button that navigates to page 2

Page2 has a camera to select from after saving to local or gallery to select from list of files.

if I use buttons to navigate.....rendering file to page2 is failing.

if i use directly....navigating without any intervention from

launching of index till page 2.....

it is working perfectly alright...

rendering the file to page.....

I am using WinJs.

WinJS.Navigation.navigate("./html/page1.html");..

All my html files are in one folder....

all my js files are in one folder....

why it is behaving like this....i could not figure out.....

please add comment to help me....thx